# Если идет нагнетание "чтобы... чтобы..." и далее множество "и чтобы", как быть с запятой перед союзом?

Tags: пунктуация

> А под песенку «Just a perfect day» задумали сделать клип из
>   видеоматериалов дельфиньего шоу. Чтоб в пронзительные моменты музыки
>   белуха выпрыгивала на высоту, чтобы синхронно ныряли дельфины в
>   рапиде, и чтоб вода в солнце играла, и брызги чтоб в разные
>   стороны, и чтобы улыбки зрителей и общая радость.

Вот здесь:

*...в рапиде, и чтоб вода...*

ставится запятая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение можно оставить без изменения (не вижу необходимости делить его на группы), **все запятые на месте**.

Это однородные придаточные: если союз И повторяется хотя бы два раза, то все запятые ставятся, интонация перечислительная.

Answer (score 1):

Это такое "вода в солнце"? Может, вода на солнце или солнце в воде?

(1)Чтоб в пронзительные моменты музыки белуха выпрыгивала на высоту, (2)чтобы синхронно ныряли дельфины в рапиде, и (3)чтоб вода в солнце играла, и (4)брызги чтоб в разные стороны, и (5)чтобы улыбки зрителей и общая радость.

Нельзя убрать занк препинания после "в рапиде", посколько (1), (2) и (3) не образуют группу. На мой взгляд, здесь можно увидеть две группы: {(1), (2)} и {(3), (4), (5)}. Вторая группа — результат первой. Я бы разделил их тире:

**Чтоб в пронзительные моменты музыки белуха выпрыгивала на высоту, чтобы синхронно ныряли дельфины в рапиде — и чтоб вода на/в солнце играла, и брызги чтоб в разные стороны, и чтобы улыбки зрителей и общая радость.**